# how to mark a test as Broken, Cancelled etc. in our jasmine tests for Allure reports

Tags: jasmine, protractor, allure, jasmine-spec-reporter

How to mark a test as Broken, Cancelled etc. in our jasmine-protractor tests so that these can appears accordingly in Allure report?

Comment: I don't know about jasmine-protractor tests, but when Junit tests are skipped, they are marked accordingly.

Comment: This is already well known to me